# function pointer without pointer in parameters

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I have this exam review and one of the questions is:
    Write a function point[er] for the function void myfun(int yourage);

I'm not exactly sure how to do anything with just that function without adding anything to the parameters.. I know the basics of function pointers and came up with a very basic scenario for what I believe solves the question, which is:

```
void myfun(int (*fptr)(int), int yourage)
{
    cout << fptr(yourage) << endl;
}
int yourage(int x)
{
    return x; //really simple
}

int main()
{
    int age = 10;
    int (*pfnc)(int);
    pfnc = yourage;
    myfun(pfnc,age);
    return 0;
}
```

I know you're not the professor and don't know how he grades but is that the only way to write a function pointer for a function or is there another way in which I don't have to change the original function?

Comment: Does it work as intended? _'I don't have to change the original function?'_ You changed which _original_ function?

Comment: If you ask me, I would call this "Making a function pointer for the function `yourage`"

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the function works but I don't think it's in the format that the professor wants. The original function is the void myfun(int yourage);

Comment: @Jeremie As for the requirement `Write a function point[er] for the function void myfun(int yourage);` looks perfectly fine for me (though the naming confuses everything a bit) ...

Comment: Were you given an original definition of `myfun`?  Show it.

Comment: @BenVoigt show it like a picture? Yeah the question kinda confused me a bit too when I read it.

Comment: By "show" I mean type in the code for the original version of `myfun` in the question.  Otherwise I don't know what the professor's version looks like.  (see my answer, I guessed)

Comment: He didn't give us anything else to go on. I wrote the question word by word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
typedef void (*pFunc)(int);
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/z4Osmj).

```
#include <iostream>

typedef void (*pFunc)(int); // declare the function pointer type

void my_function(int v) // the function you want to point to
{
    std::cout << "value = " << v << std::endl;  
}

void func(pFunc f, int v) // a function that takes a function pointer as a paramter
{
    f(v);
}

int main() 
{
    pFunc myFunc = &my_function;
    func(myFunc, 5); // call the function with a function pointer parameter
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, although I'm not even sure what the question is.

Comment: @JesseGood "I'm not exactly sure how to do anything with just that function without adding anything to the parameters." - That left me with the impression he didn't know how to declare and use a function pointer.

Comment: @ZacHowland The OP mentioned being familiar with function pointers ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ And then went to to indicate he is not.

Comment: @Zac: How so exactly?  He seemed to not understand the instructions, but his use of function pointers in the question look perfect.

Comment: @BenVoigt See the quote in response to Jesse's comment.  I agree his question is ambiguous.

Comment: Unfortunately he hasn't taught us typedef yet which seems helpful in the problem.

Comment: @Jeremie [typedef](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/)

Answer (score 1):

If the original function was:

```
void myfun(int yourage)
{
    cout << "age is: " << yourage << endl;
}
```

Then I would interpret those instructions to mean something like:

```
int main()
{
    // write a function pointer for myfun
    typedef void myfun_type(int);
    myfun_type* myfun_ptr = &myfun;

    //now use it
    int a[] = { 31, 27, 25, 23, 21, 18 };
    for_each(begin(a), end(a), myfun_ptr);
}
```